# Karma cannot find module 'optimist'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, karma-runner

I am trying to install angular phone cat app and run the test cases with karma test runner. I have node v0.10.33 installed. and I have installed karma globally. Now, i am trying to run the test cases with 'npm test' and I get following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\lib\cli.j
s:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Any idea ? I thought may be karma is not initialized right and I tried to run 'karma init' but same error again.

Update-----

On running 'npm install' i get following errors:

```
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma requires s
ocket.io@'~0.9.13' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\socket.io,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.2.0
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma requires g
lob@'~3.2.7' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma requires m
inimatch@'~0.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\minimatch,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.0
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma requires u
seragent@'~2.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\useragent,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.2
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma requires c
onnect@'~2.12.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\connect,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.3.3
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\handlebars requires optimist@'~0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\optimist,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\bower-registry-client\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data requires as
ync@'~0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\bower-registry-client\node_modules\async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.2.10
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\insight\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\cli-color\node_modules\d requires
es5-ext@'~0.10.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\me\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\insight\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\cli-color\node_modules\timers-ext
requires es5-ext@'~0.10.2' but will load
```

Comment: npm install optimist

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I am getting errors for many modules not found after installing optimist eg. lodash, useragent. Isnt karma supposed to install them? Is there something wrong with my karma installation ? I dont want to go through the process of installing each one of them seperately.

Comment: Do you have package.json file in you project ? If yes, just run npm install and all dependencies will install...

Comment: I ran 'npm install' but it gives me unmet dependency errors. I have updated the error above in the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try do next steps before run npm install

- remove folder `node_modules` from your project
- run `npm cache clean`
- run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

If you get **Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'** , try installing **optimist**.

To install optimist for any global use, try the following and reload shell

```
sudo npm install -g --save optimist
```

Or for your case, please follow the below steps:

1. Remove directory `node_modules` from project
2. Run `npm cache clean`
3. Run `npm install`